# matplotlib not showing axis title and axis names

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

i am trying to create a chart to plot some data with matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
from matplotlib import style
import datetime

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.xlabel('Days')
ax1.ylabel('Ads Posted')
ax1.title('Autoposter Performance')

def animate(i):
    pullData = open("data.txt","r").read()
    dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
    xar = []
    yar = []
    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if len(eachLine)>1:
            x,y = eachLine.split(',')
            xar.append(int(x))
            yar.append(int(y))
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar,yar, color='purple', linewidth=0.125)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

the axis names and title i set at

```
ax1.xlabel('Days')
ax1.ylabel('Ads Posted')
ax1.title('Autoposter Performance')`
```

are not showing up on the plot

[image]

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You call `ax1.clear()` which erases labels and a title. Try this putting it after the command is called:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
from matplotlib import style
import datetime
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    xar = np.arange(10)
    yar = np.arange(10)

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.set_xlabel('Days')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Ads Posted')
    ax1.set_title('Autoposter Performance')
    ax1.plot(xar,yar, color='purple', linewidth=0.125)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```